# Form is not submitting php

Tags: php, forms

I have a form field in which I have a submit button. When I'm clicking the submit button nothing happens. This is my code:

This is `combinations`:

```
$combinations = [
    40 - black,
    40 - blue,
    41 - black,
    41 - blue,
    42 - black,
    42 - blue
];

<div class="col-md-12 alert-success">
    <form id="configurable_product_form" class="configurable_form" action="" method="post">
    <?php

    $combinations = getConigurationsByCuts($pageid);
    $check_index = 0;
    foreach ($combinations as $combination) {
        if (isset($existing_configurations[$check_index])) {

        } 
    ?>

        <labe><?php echo $combination; ?></labe>
        <input class="configurable_input" type="number" name="sku_<?php echo $check_index ?>" placeholder = 'sku'/>
        <input class="configurable_input" type="number" name="price_<?php echo $check_index ?>" placeholder = 'price'/>
        <br/>
        <?php $check_index++; } ?>
        <input type="submit" value="save"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

***EDIT:***

I have this code that should run after submitting the form:

```
if (isset($_POST["sku_0"])) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($combinations); $i++){
        if (isset($_POST["sku_".$i]) && $_POST["sku_".$i]){
            $sku_to_write = $_POST["sku_".$i];
            $query = "UPDATE products_configurations SET sku = \"$sku_to_write\" WHERE product_id = \"$productid\" AND cuts = \"$combinations[$i]\";";
            $value = mysql_query($query);
        }
    }
}
if (isset($_POST["price_0"])) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($combinations); $i++){
        if (isset($_POST["price_".$i]) && $_POST["price_".$i]){
            $price_to_write = $_POST["price_".$i];
            $query = "SELECT price FROM products WHERE id = \"$productid\";";
            $value = mysql_query($query);
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($value);
            foreach ($result as $r) {
                $product_price = $r;
            }
            if ($price_to_write == $product_price){

            } else {
                $query = "UPDATE products_configurations SET price = \"$price_to_write\" WHERE product_id = \"$productid\" AND cuts = \"$combinations[$i]\";";
                $value = mysql_query($query);
            }
        }
    }
}
if (isset($_POST["enabled_0"])) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($combinations); $i++) {
        if (isset($_POST["enabled_".$i]) && $_POST["enabled_".$i]) {
            $is_checked = $_POST["enabled_".$i];
            $query = "UPDATE products_configurations SET enabled = \"$is_checked\" WHERE product_id = \"$productid\" AND cuts = \"$combinations[$i]\";";
            $value = mysql_query($query);
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is, the page does not even get reloaded after click the submit button

***EDIT 2:***

Found the problem, apparently I located my `form` inside another form which was controlled by AJAX. I took it out of there and it works charmingly!

Thank for all the help!

Comment: Please consider updating your question with a better description of what you are expecting to happen and code that is compilable so that the error can be reproduced.

Comment: @ZiggZagg I added some more information, hope it's helpful

Comment: @someone - well, with this new data - it has to be a JS issue, blocking your submit via validation or something - a simple `<form>` with input type `submit` will always work unless stopped by JavaScript

Comment: @Jamesonthedog I am working on an existing website and I don't know yet all it's functions and where they're defined and used. I do know the website's using AJAX too though. How can I figure out what's blocking it?

Comment: @Jamesonthedog I don't know if it's relevant but the moment I am inserting something to the input box, the connection's becoming no secure (left to the URI there's a lock icon)

Comment: you could use chrome dev tools for that, open the `Elements` tab and highlight the form tag. in the right `style` menu use the `event listeners` tab, look for the `submit` list and see if and what function is listening to form submits there. the "not secure" is not relevant to this issue

Comment: @Jamesonthedog I solved the issue, I updated the question with the solution. Thanks for helping, thanks to you I thought about the solution :D

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem with not defining an explicit `action` since it will simply submit to the same page (although - as @phonicx mentioned - it is not according to specs, it still works like that in all browsers)

I think your issue is that you do not handle the form in any way (at least looking at your code) so every time you "submit" the form it simply refreshes the page so it looks like nothing happens.

I would expect to see a little bit of `$var = $_POST['field_name']` in your code, to use the data that's coming via the form post

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the html code which you have defined.
I have tried this code removing the php, so there must be something wrong with the php in this code.

Let me know what you want to do with this code :

```
$combinations = [
  40 - black,
    40 - blue,
    41 - black,
    41 - blue,
    42 - black,
    42 - blue
];
```

Are you creating an array ?If yes then this is not the way.

Comment: This is not how I declare it, it's just its values so it would be more understandable

Answer (score -1):

Your form has no action defined.

You need to create a server side route to accept the POST request sent by the form when it submits.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

> action
>
> The URI of a program that processes the form information. This value
>   can be overridden by a formaction attribute on a  or 
>   element.

Comment: If action is not defined, it should post to the page itself.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Incorrect. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-action

"The action and formaction content attributes, if specified, must have a value that is a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces."

He has specified an action attribute and left it empty.

Comment: this is interesting - @phonicx is correct in saying it is against the specs. however, as all of us who tried it know, it works as mentioned (submits to itself) - in modern spec you are supposed to omit it and not leave it empty.